# On browsers, why does the interior transparent area of this SVG icon become gray at smaller sizes

Tags: html, css, svg, browser

I have a SVG icon that I want to use next to a copy in a button. So I make it 16x16, but then this causes the interior transparent area of the SVG to become gray. This only happens in browsers like Chrome and Firefox. When I resize the SVG in another desktop application like Illustrator, I don't see the weird graying effect at smaller sizes.

The following are screenshots taken from the SVG rendered in Chrome:

SVG (16x16) with grayed out interior,
[image: rounded filled plus sign]

SVG (24x24) that looks fine,
[image: rounded filled plus sign]

Here is the SVG code in question. You can save it in a file with a SVG extension and view it in a browser like Chrome to see the issue.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="510px" height="510px" viewBox="0 0 510 510" style="enable-background:new 0 0 510 510;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g id="add-circle">
        <path d="M255,0C114.75,0,0,114.75,0,255s114.75,255,255,255s255-114.75,255-255S395.25,0,255,0z M382.5,280.5h-102v102h-51v-102    h-102v-51h102v-102h51v102h102V280.5z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's just antialiasing, it's expected. You can turn it off but the outer circle will look jagged.

Comment: yea i tried adding `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to the SVG. it got rid of the graying caused by antialiasing but made the outer circle look jagged, unfortunately. i guess this is just a shortcoming of svg rendering on browsers?

Comment: Not really, you just need to create the shape differently i.e. have the outer edges antialiased and the inner edges not. That means you need to use two separate elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either edit the shape to make the cross bigger - avoiding anti-aliasing. Or you can apply a filter to the central "+" to force all semi-transparent pixels to fully transparent. This will effectively make the central "+" look bigger.

Highly recommend NOT using the filter approach and just editing the shape.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 510 510" >
  
  <defs>
    <filter id="undo-anti-aliasing">
      <feFlood x="105" y="105" width="300" height="300" flood-color="white" flood-opacity="1" result="mask"/>
      
      <feComposite operator="out" in2="mask" in="SourceGraphic" result="masked-source"/>
      
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="mask" in="SourceGraphic"/>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="masked-source"/> 
      
      
    </filter>
  </defs>
<g>
    <g id="add-circle" filter="url(#undo-anti-aliasing)">
        <path d="M255,0C114.75,0,0,114.75,0,255s114.75,255,255,255s255-114.75,255-255S395.25,0,255,0z M382.5,280.5h-102v102h-51v-102    h-102v-51h102v-102h51v102h102V280.5z"/>
    </g>
</g>

</svg>
```